# Given a matrix, how do I decide whether some values are neighbours?

Tags: algorithm, perl, matrix

I have a matrix

```
([  1,  2,  3,  4],
 [  5,  6,  7,  8],
 [  9, 10, 11, 12],
 [ 13, 14,  3, 16],
 [  2, 18, 19, 20])
```

and a search string. The task is to find out whether the numbers in the search string are values in the matrix that are near-by each other along the x and y coordinates.

- `"2,7,12,16"` should return true
- `"2,4,7,12"` should return true
- `"1,6,8,12"` should return false
- `"1,5,14,15"` should return false

---

```
&validateMatrix($number2search,\@matrix);

sub validateMatrix{
    my($a,$d) = @_;
    my @s = split(",",$a);
    my @matrix = @{$d};

    ???
    ??
    return(true or false)
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have written and describe the problem you're having

Comment: I need the algorithm on how perl can solve the condition above. Thanks

Comment: I've tried using the A-star Pathfinding by converted non matched element to zero, but still...... need a proper algorithm to handle this !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you consider neighbors in your algorithm. Is the matrix considered cyclical?  In either case, the algorithm would be as follows.

1. Create a mapping from numbers to start positions: Hash of Number to Array of Position.
2. Create a neighbor mapping for all positions: Hash of Position to (Hash of Number to Array of Position) -- or just Hash of Number to Position if you can only have one neighbor with that number.
3. For each search string:

   1. initialize position possibilities to the array returned by the start mapping.
   2. Iterate through remaining numbers, getting next position set from the neighbor mapping for the possibilities.
   3. If you have no position possibilities left, it's not a match.

Step 2 is optional because you could just iterate through the neighbors looking for a match inside the search step, but it helps separate out the concerns.

And the start mapping could also be considered just a special position that neighbors all other positions, which simplifies the later algorithm as well because you don't have to special case the first number in the search string.

Comment: Hi; TimTom, Thanks for the algorithm let me work it out the script.

Comment: Hi; TimTom, if the neighbor having multiple same number then the returned position will not be correct.

Comment: It is correct. That's why in step two we have a hash of position to Hash of Number to Array of Position. I even specifically called that out in the comments that if you didn't have that you could do something else.

Comment: Perhaps you were confused by step 3.2, that doesn't get one result. It is a set of current positions to a set of next positions.

Comment: Hi; TimTom , Thanks for the algorithm , is working .